# Add link to image rotator

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to figure out how i would go about adding a link to the image rotator
I got the images to rotate but the issue is making them clickable I don't know jquery that well so i was wondering what would be the easiest way to do this.

The html is below

```
      <div class="fadein">
       <img src="/site/images/hp-d-rotate-t.jpg" alt="ad rotator" />
       <img src="/site/images/hp-d-rotate-e.jpg" alt="ad rotator" /> 
      </div>
```

and the jquery is below:

```
<script>
  $(function(){
  $('.fadein img:gt(0)').hide();
  setInterval(function(){$('.fadein :first-child').fadeOut().next('img').fadeIn().end().appendTo('.fadein');}, 4000);
});
</script>
```

I want each image to link to a page.What would be the best way to fix this without making too many changes to the jquery (Link is going to change for each image)

```
<a href ="ab1.html"><img src="/site/images/hp-d-rotate-t.jpg" alt="rotator" /></a>
<a href ="ab2.html"><img src="/site/images/hp-d-rotate-e.jpg" alt="rotator" /></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`wrap`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) method for this:

```
$( '.fadein img' ).wrap( '<a href=""></a>' );
```

Comment: where would i add that?

Comment: but the link is going to change for each image

Comment: and what links it should be? They didn't mentioned in question

Comment: Sorry. Each rotator image will be linking to another page. Each link will be different according to image.

Comment: and how you will know what link related to image?

Comment: is there a way to add the link to the html instead and just change the jquery accordingly. I edited the question

Comment: Yes, change `.next('img')...` to `.next('a')...` and `$('.fadein img:gt(0)')` to `$('.fadein a:gt(0)')`